# how to compare two array data and listing out missing data -- collections exists method

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have requirement as below, have two list, find out which element is missing from list comparing with other list. In below example used exist method, but after executing this I came to know we cannot use exist in this way, it will work only with index. please guide me which method will help me to meet this type of requirement
TABLE - MISSEVETEST(PID, DIR, EVE_NAME)
SAMPLE DATA - 111, O, CN.. 111, O, SN output:-  is RPI is missing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EVE_MISS_POC IS
  TYPE t_missing_eve IS TABLE OF MISSEVETEST%ROWTYPE;
  list_missing_eve t_missing_eve := t_missing_eve();
  TYPE t_out_eve IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(80); 
  varray_out_eve t_out_eve;
  CURSOR c_missing_eve is SELECT PID, DIR, EVE_NAME FROM MISSEVETEST;
  current_pid PAY.PID%TYPE;
  TYPE t_pid_present_eve IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(80); 
  varray_pid_present_eve t_puid_present_eve := t_puid_present_eve();
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCESS STARTRED');
  varray_out_eve := t_out_eve('CN', 'SN', 'RPI');
  OPEN c_missing_eve;
    LOOP
      -- processing payment records in batches. Each batch - 10000 records
      FETCH c_missing_eve bulk collect INTO list_missing_eve limit 10000; 
      BEGIN
        current_pid := list_missing_eve(1).PID; --assign first pid from list 
        FOR index_eve IN 1 .. list_missing_eve.count
        LOOP
           --this will collect all events belongs to same puid
           IF current_pid = list_missing_eve(index_eve).PID THEN
            varray_pid_present_eve.EXTEND;
            -- collect all events of same puid
            varray_pid_present_eve(varray_pid_present_eve.count) := list_missing_eve(index_eve).EVE_NAME;
           ELSE
            FOR i IN 1..varray_out_eve .COUNT LOOP
              IF varray_pid_present_eve.EXISTS(varray_out_eve (i)) THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EVENT:' ||varray_out_eve (i) ||' EXIST');
              ELSE
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EVENT:' ||varray_out_eve (i) ||' NOT EXIST');
              END IF;
            END LOOP;
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END;
      EXIT WHEN c_missing_eve%notfound;
    END LOOP; -- End for limit loop
    CLOSE c_missing_eve;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had used `NESTED TABLE` instead of `VARRAY`, you could have used the `MULTISET EXCEPT` operator.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
   TYPE vtype IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (10);

   v1   vtype
           := vtype ('ABC',
                     'DEF',
                     'GHI',
                     'KLM');
   v2   vtype := vtype ('ABC', 'DEF');
   v3   vtype := vtype ();
BEGIN
   v3 := v1 MULTISET EXCEPT v2;


   FOR i IN v3.FIRST .. v3.LAST
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v3 (i));
   END LOOP;
END;
/

GHI
KLM
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will change it to Nested Table